# OTP Verification with Twilio - how to keep user logged in after verification

Tags: twilio

Using [Twilio Verify API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api) to authenticate the user via SMS.
I do not want the user to keep doing the OTP process every time he opens the app - I want to keep him authenticated once he completed the OTP for the first time.
How do I do that - should I generate a token somehow after he logged in?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: What platform have you built this app on? How is the rest of your user authentication handled?

Comment: Thanks @philnash for commenting - working in React-Native env. currently no authentication mechanism chosen, I thought twilio is enough - am I wrong?

Comment: Answering to myself - Yes I was wrong - Twilio is not enough, once you validate the the twilio process you need to create a token and send it to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have authenticated the user you will want to store something that you can check to see whether they have authenticated. Normally this would be a token of some sort that can be used to access any remote services, but it doesn't have to be.

The [answer marked as correct on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55877260/best-way-for-persist-user-authentication-in-react-native) is a good explanation of how to do this, but it should also be noted that storing a token in unencrypted storage is a potential security issue, so you should also pay attention to the highest voted answer with the links to secure storage libraries.